# Finding a Webshell script in User home directories.

Tags: malware, php, shellcode

We recently had an issue with one of our servers. We want to scan our User's home directories in order to detect if there are in `Web Shell` Scripts present.

We have implemented a script to list all file types in the `public_html` directory of 400 so User directories but we are having trouble determining which script whether `.php` or shell type is malignant.

Is there a way to find out or differentiate between normal web `.php` scripts from malignant scripts.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many approximations to find for LFI,RFI, Webshells, Password Grabs, Web Scanners so you could do the following :

1. Start by checking my **access logs**, it really depends what webserver I'm  using, for this part you could use different tools but if you want to build your own tool you maybe want something to start like the Irongeek's Logwatch [Script](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/logwatch-script-grep-for-rfis-webscanners-webshell-attacks) which is a little old but this will give you some ideas.
2. Search site folders/directories for **suspicious files** like the popular backdoors that are readily available on the internet

> ```
> sploitpattern='r0nin|m0rtix|upl0ad|r57shell|cFaTaLisTiCz_Fx|Tukulesto|99shell|shellbot|phpshell|void.ru|phpremoteview|directmail|bash_history|.ru/|brute*force|multiviews|cwings|vandal|bitchx|eggdrop|guardservices|psybnc|dalnet|undernet|vulnscan|spymeta|raslan58|Webshell'
>
> find ./ ( -regex '.*.php$' -o -regex '.*.cgi$' -o -regex '.*.inc$' ) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep -il "$sploitpattern" | sort >potential_exploits.txt
> ```

3. Search site files for suspicious content with grep/findstr
   using grep command line tool because most vulnerable web applications use the shell_exec,or include things like PHP vulnerable functions, so  [searching](http://blog.rootcon.org/2012/04/simple-kung-fu-grep-for-finding-common.html) for the shell_exec and inclusions in folders to check for the possible PHP files that are vulnerable to RCE or command injection.

> ```
> grep -Rn 'shell_exec *(' /var/www
> grep -Rn 'include *(' /var/www
> grep -Rn 'require *(' /var/www
> grep -Rn 'include_once *(' /var/www
> grep -Rn 'require_once *(' /var/www
> grep -Rn 'base64_decode *(' /var/www
> ```

Comment: I needed to maks the parens with a backslash on my machine, otherwise I got a bash error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token ')'`